# I am making a simple typing game with fruit, and my main goal is to have it show the correct and total amount of keypresses, and the accuracy of those

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, global-variables

When the last letter(apple) on the screen is pressed, the correct and total amount of key presses need to appear, along with the accuracy of those keypresses. So far, I have only managed to get to the last letter being pressed.

```
import turtle as trtl
import random as rand

#-----setup-----]
apple_image = "apple.gif"
pear_image = "pear.gif" # Store the file name of your shape
font_setup = ('Ariel', 20, 'normal')

wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.bgpic("background.gif")
wn.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)
wn.addshape(apple_image) # Make the screen aware of the new file
wn.addshape(pear_image)

    

letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
curr_letters = []

correct = 0
total = 0
```

The start of the program should be perfectly fine, but I think it could be that I am using the global variables wrong.

```
def draw_fruit(active_fruit, letter):
    vowels = ['A','E','I','O','U']
    if letter in vowels:
        active_fruit.shape(pear_image)
    else:
        active_fruit.shape(apple_image)
    draw_letter(active_fruit, letter)
    wn.update()


def apple_drop(letter):
    index = curr_letters.index(letter)
    curr_letters.pop(index)
    active_apple = apples.pop(index)
    active_apple.clear()
    curr_xcor = active_apple.xcor()
    active_apple.goto(curr_xcor,-150)
    active_apple.hideturtle()
    apple_reset(active_apple)
    apples.append(active_apple)
    

def draw_letter(active_apple, curr_letter):
    global letters, curr_letters
    curr_xcor = active_apple.xcor()
    curr_ycor = active_apple.ycor()
    active_apple.color("white")
    wn.tracer(False)
    active_apple.goto(curr_xcor - 18, curr_ycor - 40)
    active_apple.write(curr_letter, font=("Ariel", 55, 'bold'))
    active_apple.goto(curr_xcor , curr_ycor)
    wn.tracer(True)

def apple_reset(active_apple):
    if len(letters) != 0:
        rand_x = rand.randint(-200,200)
        rand_y = rand.randint(-25,100)
        active_apple.goto(rand_x, rand_y)
        active_apple.showturtle()
        curr_letter = letters.pop(rand.randint(0,len(letters)-1))
        curr_letters.append(curr_letter)
        draw_fruit(active_apple, curr_letter)
```

This is the section that controls the main game. The letters are drawn onto the apples, the apples are dropped, and then reset. The letters are popped, and then added into the empty list.

```
def correct_presses():
    global correct, total
    correct_displayer.hideturtle()
    correct_displayer.penup()
    correct_displayer.goto(-250,250)
    correct_displayer.pendown()
    correct_displayer.write("You got",correct,"amount of keypresses!", font=font_setup)

def total_presses():
    global correct, total
    total_displayer.hideturtle()
    total_displayer.penup()
    total_displayer.goto(250,250)
    total_displayer.pendown()
    total_displayer.write("You clicked",total,"amount of times.", font=font_setup)

def accuracy_of_presses():
    global correct, total
    accuracy_displayer.hideturtle()
    accuracy_displayer.penup()
    accuracy_displayer.goto(0,250)
    accuracy_displayer.pendown()
    accuracy_displayer.write("You got",correct//total*100,"percent of your keypresses correct.", font=font_setup)

def end_of_game():
    global correct, total
    if len(curr_letters) == 26:
        correct_presses()
        total_presses()
        accuracy_of_presses()
```

THIS is the main section that I am having problems with. I do not fully understand why this code will not function correctly, and what is missing from it in order to have it appear on the screen. Of course, you would need the keypresses for the game to work, but I do not think that would help me figure out the problem with the code.

```
apples = []
for apple in range(5):
    apple = trtl.Turtle()
    apple.speed(0)
    apple.penup()
    apple.hideturtle()
    apples.append(apple)
    apple_reset(apple)
print(curr_letters)

correct_displayer = trtl.Turtle()
total_displayer = trtl.Turtle()
accuracy_displayer = trtl.Turtle()
```

I expected the keypresses that I coded to appear on the screen after I clicked on the last letter on the screen. After I did that, nothing else happened on the screen.